# Accessing value in specific field of FeatureSet using Arcade

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade, feature-set

I am working on an ArcGIS Online app, where I need to evaluate the value in a specific field of a selected feature. I want to do something like this:

```
var myFeature = FeatureSetByName($selection, "my_polygons")

if (myFeature.field_name == "text 1") {
    return variable1
} else if (myFeature.field_name == "text 2") {
    return variable2
} else {
    return variable3
};
```

While this would work on a `$feature` object, it is not the case with `FeatureSet`.

`$selection` is fairly specific Global variable that was designed to work for my type of App, but essentially it work in the exact same way as `$map`.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: To query the structure of a FeatureSet to see if it has a specific field I think you need to be using the [Schema()](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#schema) function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a Feature from a FeatureSet by using the [First](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#first) function. If there are more than one feature in that featureset, you can use the [Filter](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#filter) function to make sure you get the specific one you want.